# Iterator<Int> in Swift

Tags: swift, iterator

I am writing a trie in swift.  I have written the same code in java, where I accept an instance of `Iterator<Int>` as a parameter to specify the location of the trie elements.

In swift I cannot find the same simple interface.
The forms

`public func put(path: Iterator<Int>) {...}`

and

`public func put(path: IteratorProtocol<Int>) {...}`

give me compile errors, so I am currently using

`public func put(path: AnyIterator<Int>) {...}`

but this seems ugly, and forces the caller to create an extra arbitrary object.  Is there a better way?  I cannot believe that swift does not have an elegant idiom..... I just cannot find it.

Comment: This would be practice in Java. Why require the caller to call `iterator()` for you? You should accept a `Collector<Integer>` or `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks for commenting, and I hear what you say, but the sequence of integers defines the location of the element in the tree/trie.  The trie is traversed at each node, so a collection would also need to carry an offset into the collection making it a special object.  Iterator does the job well by releasing a sequence of integers and keeping track of the next one.  A perfect fit for the job. And the source of the integers could be anything - even a string, so the iterator approach seems the minimum requirement on the caller.

Comment: Using an Iterator is an implementation detail that I think you should keep encapsulated within your type, don't expose it through your public API.

Comment: @Alexander: Sounds good, but I am not sure what would replace the iterator in the interface.  The position in tree/trie is defined by a sequence of integers that is consumed as the the tree is navigated. Think of it as the 'key' of a 'map' where the value is a trie element that can hold the user's data.  Any other data structure would be more restrictive. I have both the swift and the java versions on bitbucket and would welcome suggestions for remodelling the interface.

Comment: In Java, Collection or List, in Swift, Sequence. I already said this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of Iterator is Sequence.

```
func put<S: Sequence>(path: S) where S.Element == Int
```

Of course you don't need the `where` clause if you don't care about the type of the elements.

Typically a trie would itself be generic over its own Element, so it'd be something like

```
struct Trie<Element: Comparable> {
    func put<S: Sequence>(path: S) where S.Element == Element { ... }
}
```

If you really want to accept iterators directly, you can, but this is pretty rare. It would be along these lines:

```
func put<I: IteratorProtocol>(path: inout I) where I.Element == Int
```

To directly make use of an iterator, you need to modify it, and that means you need it to be `inout` (or you could return a copy of it, but can be dangerous since advancing multiple copies of an iterator is undefined). This is really unusual, though. You likely mean `Sequence`.

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what I need.  The iterator syntax is ugly, but thats the chap.  I need an iterator as each element in the trie determines/creates a child based upon the next integer, and then passes the iterator to that child.  Where can I read more about that syntax - it seems a bit opaque to me.

Comment: The trie is generic, but the integer 'path' is the means of navigating the trie/tree. The low level implementation only deals with the structure, but each node can carry a genric user value.  I am still shaking down the details but there is some code here [https://bitbucket.org/drphill/swifttrie]

Answer (score 0):

Having tried the function signatures suggested by Rob Napier and encountering problems I have implemented my own protocol:

`public protocol PathIterator {
    func next() -> Int?
}`

And some concrete implementations to wrap String or [Int].  I would still like to find out how to do this in a swiftian manner, but I am more keen to get the code written and functioning.  I am still open to suggestions.